# Filter and join values into one cell in Excel

Tags: excel

I would like to filter and combine returned cells into one cell in Excel.

Products sheet:

| SKU | Product Name | Color | Brand | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CellP1 | iPhone 14 | Red | Apple | 1 |
| CellP2 | Android 13 | Green | Sams | 0 |
| CellP3 | iPhone 12 | Gold | Apple | 1 |
| CellP4 | Android 15 | Black | Sams | 1 |
| CellP5 | iPhone 16 | Green | Apple | 0 |

Export sheet:

conditions:

- Brand == Apple
- Stock > 0
- Product Name = [Product Name + " " + Color]

| Product Name | Stock |
| --- | --- |
| iPhone 14 Red | 1 |
| iPhone 12 Gold | 1 |

I tried several things, this was the closest to what I want to achieve:

```
=FILTER({Products!B2:B,Products!C2:C,Products!E2:E},REGEXMATCH(Products!D2:D, "Apple"))
```

...but I can't combine product name and color into one cell.

Comment: `REGEXMATCH` is not an excel function. It belongs to Google Spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try in `H2` cell the following:

```
=FILTER(HSTACK(B2:B6 &" "& C2:C6, E2:E6), (D2:D6=G2) * (E2:E6 > 0))
```

Or using `LET` function to define the input variables first and for easy reading of the expression:

```
=LET(rng, A2:E6, prod, INDEX(rng,,2), color, INDEX(rng,,3), 
  brands, INDEX(rng,,4), stocks, INDEX(rng,,5), brand, G2, 
  FILTER(HSTACK(prod &" "& color, stocks) , (brands=brand) * (stocks > 0) )
)
```

here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

If your excel version doesn't have `HSTACK` available, just replace this call with:

```
CHOOSE({1,2}, prod &" "& color, stocks)
```

If you want to generate the headers as part of the output, then you can use `VSTACK` for that (if you have it available in your Excel version):

```
=LET(rng, A2:E6, prod, INDEX(rng,,2), color, INDEX(rng,,3), 
  brands, INDEX(rng,,4), stocks, INDEX(rng,,5), brand, G2, 
  VSTACK({"Product Name", "Stock"},
    FILTER(HSTACK(prod &" "& color, stocks) , (brands=brand) * (stocks > 0) )
  )
)
```